# I want to create custom UI-SWITCH controller in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, uiswitch

I want to create Custom **UISwitch** button, what will i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this library: [RCSwitch](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/). Should be exactly what you want.